# C#: Проблема с с русским языком в MultipartFormDataContent

Tags: c#, http, post, fileupload

**Добрый день.**

Вот код, который отправляет файл POST-запросом на сервер по урлу:

```
fileName = "русские_символы_12345";
var url = "......";
var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var dataContent = new ByteArrayContent(documentByteArray);
requestContent.Add(dataContent, "file", fileName);
```

Проблема в том, что при отправке  я получаю BadRequest потому что в Content-Disposition при отправке записывается такое:

> Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file;
>   filename="=?utf-8?B?0J/QoNCY0JzQldCgXzEyMzQ1Njc4LnBkZg==?=";
>   filename*=utf-8''%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%A0_12345678.pdf

И имя файла тут не такое как отправялось, а : `filename="=?utf-8?B?0J/QoNCY0JzQldCgXzEyMzQ1Njc4LnBkZg==?="`
тут даже расширения нету, собственно из-за того что тут нету расширения я и получаю 400ую.

Подскажите, есть ли какой-то рабочий способ отправить в `MultipartFormDataContent` файл с кириллическим именем?

Или может другой способ использовать какой-то?

Спасибо